# How to create a self updating javascript script

Tags: javascript, version, auto-update, self-updating

*Hi, I would like to create a self-updating js script that checks for new version and if there's a new one it updates...*

- **it could check if theres a change from a url (for example github raw link)**
- **or maybe check the version from a url and if he finds a defferent version it updates...**

---

*like this is the old script:*

```
alert("im an old script");
```

*and this is the new one uploaded on github:*

```
alert("im the new one, all old scripts needs to update!")
```

---

i mean not a javascript on a website just a javascript on an userscript manager
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt before posting here. What have you tried?

Comment: there are multiple options: 
-use url based script tag
-use cdn, configure github to auto deploy on your cdn when you make change and use url from cdn as a script tag

Comment: i mean not a javascript on a website justa  javascript on an userscript manager